# Can't display table contents that contain URL's from database

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I'm a student using NetBeans to create very basic webpage(s) using HTML, PHP and SQLite. So far, everything is fine. The problem I have is that images aren't displayed on the `moviedetails.php` page. Everything else including the `titles`, `ratings` and `description` for each table entry works fine. (I am retrieving rows from a database table.) Here is my code:

(This is very new to me, so if it's a simple mistake, sorry for wasting your time :/)

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $pdo = new PDO('sqlite:movies.db');             //Import SQLite database "movies.db" to a Var
    $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM movie");

    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        //For each id number in db, echo a hyperlink containing that ID's title and 
        echo '<a href="moviedetails.php?id=' . htmlentities($row['id']) . '">' . htmlentities($row['title']) . '</a>';
        echo '<br>';
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

**moviedetails.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    $pdo = new PDO('sqlite:movies.db');                                //Using movies.db
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM movie WHERE id=:id");        //Prepare this statement
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);   //GET INPUT from Variable 'id' and FILTER anything which isn't a number 
    $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);                     //Bind :name 'id' to a $id variable
    $query->execute();                                                 //Execute the prepared statement
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                            //Fetch next row of results


    //var_dump($row);
    //display title, description and rating
    echo '<h1>'.htmlentities($row['title']).'</h1>';                //Echo 'Title' from db into a heading
    echo '<a href="'.htmlentities($row['image']).'"></a>';          //Echo 'image from db into a link
    echo '<p>'.htmlentities($row['description']).'</p>';            //Echo 'description' from db to paragraph
    echo '<p>Rating: '. htmlentities($row['rating']).'</p>';         //Echo 'rating' from db to paragraph
    ?>


</body>
```

Here is my database in an image, as this is the easiest way to show you:
http://i.cubeupload.com/TBI5Fv.png

Here is one of the webpages that should diplay a link. However, it contains only the other table fields:
http://i.cubeupload.com/1tcfsU.png

The strange thing is, it doesn't give me any errors, so I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<a>` tag is empty, so it's invisible.

```
echo '<a href="'.htmlentities($row['image']).'"></a>';
```

You should put some content that will be displayed as a link like this:

```
echo '<a href="'.htmlentities($row['image']).'">THIS IS LINK TO IMAGE</a>';
```

If you want to display the image itself instead of a link, you should use `<img>` tag like this:

```
echo '<img src="'.htmlentities($row['image']).'"/>';
```

Comment: Thank!

In the meantime, I realised I was trying to use the <img src=""> tag....
Edit: the image appears to be linked, but is broken. Not sure why this would occur :/ http://i.cubeupload.com/4HW5dO.png